# JTextField.getText() returns null value even if it has content inside

Tags: java, swing, null, jtextfield, file-read

I have a portion of code that takes the text of a TextField (there are two TextFields actually, but the user can use only one at a time) and search it into a file stored into the terminal. The problem is that I always get a null string, even when there is text into one of the TextFields...
This is the code (the assignation is on the method actionPerformed():

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Search implements ActionListener{
JFrame frame;
JButton click;
JLabel comando, carico;
JTextField textv, text;
JTextArea res;
String pathFile = "C:\\Log.txt";
String str= new String();

Search(){

    frame = new JFrame("Search");
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1));
    click = new JButton("Cerca");
    comando = new JLabel("Comando");
    carico = new JLabel("A carico di:");
    textv = new JTextField("");
    text = new JTextField("");
    res = new JTextArea("");
    panel.add(comando);
    panel.add(textv);
    panel.add(carico);
    panel.add(text);
    panel.add(click);
    res.setLineWrap(true);
    res.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    res.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(res);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    panel.add(scroller);
    frame.add(panel);
    click.addActionListener(this);      
    click.setSize(70, 35);      
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==click){
        res.setText(null);
        if(textv != null) {cercaStringa(pathFile, textv.getText().toString());}
        else {cercaStringa(pathFile, text.getText().toString());}
    }
}

public void cercaStringa(String pathFile, String stringa){
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile));
        String line = new String();
        while((line = in.readLine())!=null) {   
            if(line.contains(stringa)){
                res.append(line);
                res.append("\n");
                }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
    }



public static void main (String[] args){
    new Search();
}
```

}

I'm really going to throw everything outside the window cause I know the solution is simple but I can't get it...

Comment: I just tested your code and it works as expected. What error do you have exactly? Do you get an exception? Have you tried debugging the code? Have you tried putting println statements to see if your variable have the value you expect? Did you copy the code exactly as it is?

Comment: `cercaStringa: asdad
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Log.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)...`

Comment: Same here. Besides a few layout and encoding issues, the code seems to work. As suggested in another question, now may be the time to learn using a debugger.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You need to create the file before running the program

Comment: @assylias *"Have you tried putting println statements.."* Perhaps I should have mentioned that the `cercaStringa: asdad` output was the result of doing exactly that.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson haha :-) sorry.

Comment: @assylias  No problem. :-) Thanks for pointing out that my communication was not clear.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I used the debugger like 100 times. When I get to the assignation of the results to the JTextArea every single line that there is in the file appears here... I mean: I should have, in the JTextArea (where the program should put the results), only those lines that contains a specified word. This doesn't happen...

Comment: @assylias no I don't get any exception... I simply don't get the results that I should be getting...

Comment: @LeonGuerrero maybe you could post the content of the file or a part of it and post the string you use in textv. Also, note that textv is never null.

Comment: @LeonGuerrero Your question states "I always get a null string, even when there is text into one of the TextFields". Now you say that you don't get the right value in the JTextArea. Can you be more specific about what you are asking for?

Comment: Ok I'll go with an example... 
I have a file like this: Real Madrid Cristiano Ronaldo-Barcelona Leo Messi-McDonalds Big Mac-Berlin capital of Germany. So I have 4 different lines...
I enter into one of the JTEXTFIELD (so textv OR text) the string that I want to search; let's choose "BIG". The method cercaStringa uses String.contains() to find a match and it should write into the JTEXTAREA (that's NOT JTextField used for the input) only the line "McDonalds Big Mac"... Instead it writes every line that exists in the file... And this is caused by the fact that getText() returns a null value...

Comment: When I use your example and enter Big, the text area only contains one line (McDonalds Big Mac). Are you sure you use a valid line separator in your text file? Also if getText() returned null, you would get a null pointer exception so it can't be that.

Comment: @assylias I swear: I copied the code exactly as it is on my pc... and when I run the project, it gives me back all the lines in the file o.O

Comment: @LeonGuerrero I think the problem is in your text file. How did you create it?

Comment: Basically I have another form in which there are four JTextField. The code takes the text from these fields and saves it in a file with the printLine() method... This is the code that saves the string into the file:  
    public void Scrivi(String a) throws IOException {
  FileWriter outputStream = null;  
  outputStream = new FileWriter("C:\\Log.txt", true);
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
  pw.println(a);
  pw.close();
  outputStream.close();
 }

Comment: Calling println(String) may or may not use the line seperator that you think it's using. The line sperator that it will use is the one defined within system property "line.seperator" and is not necessarily the single newline character "\n".

Comment: Actually when I debug the project it runs the code line per line... So I think that's not the problem... @ChadNC

Comment: Not sure if you are still having problems with your code or not, I know this comment is coming several years later, but I see you are initializing BufferedReader in as both a file reader and a buffered reader. Would this not cause the issue you were seeing of the full file lines being put in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed by the following test, your fields ***are not `null`*** as of the `actionListener` call. For example, input of `"Comando"` and `"Carico"` outputs `"Test: Comando"` followed by `"Test: Carico"`, as expected:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (e.getSource() == click) {
    res.setText(null);
    System.out.println("Test: "+textv.getText());
    System.out.println("Test: "+text.getText());
    if (textv != null) {
      cercaStringa(pathFile, textv.getText().toString());
    } else {
      cercaStringa(pathFile, text.getText().toString());
    }
  }
}
```

---

The problem is that `if (textv != null)` will never reach the "else" at the first run (as far as I can tell in the quick-look I gave the code, it never will on ***any*** run, as `textv` is never set `null`), because `textv = new JTextField("");` is not equivalent to `textv = null`, and `textv` will still be holding a String, albeit it's an empty one.

The fix is this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if (e.getSource() == click) {
    res.setText("");
    if (!textv.getText().isEmpty()) {
      cercaStringa(pathFile, textv.getText().toString());
    } else {
      cercaStringa(pathFile, text.getText().toString());
    }
  }
}
```

---

You were also missing a verification for the existence of `C:\Log.txt`, and an exception could be easily triggered.

Here is the quick-fix, in the Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  File log = new File("C:\\Log.txt");
  if (!log.exists()) {
    try {
      /*
       * mkdirs() is not really needed when using the C root,
       * but I like to do this because the path might be changed.
       */
      if (!log.getParentFile().exists()) {
        log.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      }
      log.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
  Search search = new Search();
}
```

Comment: I didn't say that the file is missing ;)

Comment: Corrected. Sorry about that. Btw, can you provide the exception you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting no exception. The problem is that I don't get the results that I should be getting. I should get only those lines that contains a certain string; instead I get the entire content of the file... everything because when I get text from the JTextField it says it's empty...

Comment: Found your problem (probably...). Edited answer.

Comment: Works just as you say you want it to on my pc after putting in the changes suggested by TheLima. The only way I can see where you will get the entire file being displayed in the textarea is when both text boxes are empty.

Comment: Ok @TheLima I'd say that you deserve all my love xD

Comment: @TheLima regarding the control of the file, Eclipse says that Logger and Level cannot be resolved

Comment: Oh and one last question: how can I set the JTextArea (the area where results are written) so it resizes automatically based on the results?

Comment: About the Logger & Level, i use NetBeans, and it recommends using that method (printStackTrace() gives a warning). To fix it you can replace the line(s) with yourExVar.printStackTrace(), or import the missing classes (import java.util.logging.Level; import java.util.logging.Logger;). ----- As for automatic resizing, my tip is "Don't do it". 1-It will (very) easily breach your screen's boundaries on any larger files, unless you code a limiter (with then must be adaptive, as diff. users use diff. screens), and 2-It is plain simply inconvenient for the program's users ("unpredictable" GUIs).

Answer (score 0):

use [JTextArea#read(Reader in, Object desc) throws IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29), this method accepting line separator e.i.

Comment: Never used that function before, but doesn't it print the entire file to the text area? If that is the case, his problem would still remain, as he wants only the lines that contain the input to show up. REF:

    if (line.contains(stringa)) {
      res.append(line);
      res.append("\n");
    }